# Android expand layout on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, expand

I'm trying to achieve the following: I have a layout containing a couple of elements (textviews and in some cases an imageview), the text in one of the textView might be long, so I'd like to hide it and show it once my layout is clicked on, this is like what happens in android lollipop recents (the field expands showing "call back" and "details")

[image]

[image]

I tried doing so with an animation but it looks lousy. is there predefined code to do so ?

ps: It's also like the notification expansion in android lollipop

Thanks